# Trigger create/last update time in sqldeveloper

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to find out when a trigger was created or its last update date in sql developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select object_name, created, last_ddl_time
from user_objects
where object_type = 'TRIGGER'
```